# Are questions about which is the best/most popular <X> on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, public-beta

Notice that the above title gives this message:

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

I know based on other meta questions we allow, but do not encourage, "list of " questions - but how far is too far?

How should these questions be viewed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as the prompt suggests - view (and close) them as subjective.

Both this site and Gaming seem to be suffering from a glut of these questions at the moment.

Unless there's a specific question lurking in there:

> I need an alternative to X because of Y and Z.

the question is just after a list. If it can be restated in this way then it's fine.

Comment: So should I try to rephrase the question if possible ? or close it ? There are currently only 14 users with editing power and 44 with closing power (yet there are only about handful active at a time so questions that should be closed end up dragging along or excuse themselves into CW mode.)

Comment: @phwd - you could try and rephrase it, but if it's unrecoverable close it.