# Answers to my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153767/why-did-my-youtube-comment-disappear) a few days back, but I never received an answer. After that, I also placed a bounty on this question, yet I have not received an answer. I cannot understand why I am not getting any answer.

Comment: Have you already read https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers?

Comment: @Rubén I put a bounty.

Comment: It looks to me that you missed the first part "First, make sure you’ve [asked a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). "

Comment: I asked a question about YouTube.

Comment: That doesn't make it to be a good question.

Comment: But I really need to ask about the situation I am facing on YouTube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tl;Dr the [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153767/why-did-my-youtube-comment-disappear) doesn't look to be a high quality question, it doesn't look to be a good fit for this site as it's very likely that only the comments moderators might answer it. Also it looks that you added the bounty too soon.

---

First you should have in mind that there is no warranty that all questions will get an answer, second there is no warranty that if the question is able to get answers they will be posted in certain time frame.

In order to have more chances to get an answer you might try to:

1. Write a very good question

   - Make your question easy to ready, interesting, complete and helpful for others
2. Answer other questions

   - The way that we say "thanks" here is by accepting, upvoting and **answering questions**
3. Share your question with people that might be interested on it.

Related

- [How do I write a great question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3857/88163)

Resources

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers