# Best practices for recommending a web app or other tool

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, answers

I understand that questions asking for app recommendations (or even just "if such an app exists") are off-topic. Questions should be about problems to solve.

Sometimes, though, the best solution to a problem is an app or tool that has already been built.

**What are the best practices for answering a question with an app recommendation to avoid getting downvotes or, worse, deleted as spam?**

---

Related:

- [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: [SU] has [a similar QA](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), apparently. I don't know how much of it I want to go back and crib for our purposes.

Comment: Should we point new "answerers" to this thread? There is a old question that just got an answer suggesting the use of an app ->[How to disable Google's doodle](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33920/88163)

Comment: @Rubén: If they're leaving answers that lack useful information, yeah. That's kind of the point. In the same way we want to point people toward the question (and answer) about asking a question that might prompt an app recommendation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, very often someone has recognized the very problem the Asker has and built something to address it. "Why re-invent the wheel?" as the old saw goes.

By all means, *do* recommend an app if it will solve the Asker's problem. **Just don't simply leave a link as an answer and move on.**

An ideal answer will provide a link to the app, a basic description (perhaps even quoted from the site itself), and, probably most importantly, *will explain **how** the app/tool will solve the Asker's problem*. If you've used the app yourself, a short anecdote about how it helped you would also be useful.

It's also okay to recommend an app that *you* have created, [but remember](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/promotion):

- you must disclose your affiliation *every* time
- if all (or most) of your answers are hawking your product(s), the community is not going to look on that favorably, even with disclosure

### Bad:

You can use widget-breaker for this. It's great!

### Good:

I think the [WidgetBreaker](http://www.example.net) Chrome Extension will work for you. It's designed to frob your widgets when they get de-frobbed. Since you're trying to foo the bar, this should do what you need. Just:

1. Create your profile
2. Set the widget-frobber to use your Google Account
3. Mark the bars to be foo'd

I had a similar situation with my bazzes, and this fixed them right up.

(Note: I am not the developer, just a satisfied user.)

---

These are just basic examples, not templates.

To recap:

### Do:

- Link to the app/tool
- Explain how it will solve the Asker's problem
- Disclose your affiliation to the product, if any

### Don't:

- *Just* link to the app (or, worse, just name the app without even a link)
- Make all (or a large portion) of your answers to promote your product(s)
- Neglect to say *how* the app will solve the problem