# Overzealous app recommendation closing/deleting

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

So, here's [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7044) that was closed for being an app recommendation request, and then later deleted. Since only 10k users can see it, I'll quote it here:

> **Is there a way (an app maybe) to find like-minded people on Facebook?**
>
> We like stuff everyday, and it would be nice to find the people with whom one has the most shared likes, and socialize with them.
>
> Is there such an app or a way in general?

I disagree with its closing and especially its deletion. The question has a fairly well-defined problem statement. The mention of an app is merely an aside to indicate that the Asker is willing to use a third-party tool.

Further, the best answer on the question doesn't even recommend a third-party app.

For those with the privilege to do so, I urge you to undelete and re-open.

I've also seen other questions in the Close Vote Review queue that are similar. Let me expand on that:

I think we can all agree that questions like

> What's the best X app?

and

> What's your favorite app to do Y?

and similar questions are terrible, and should be closed and deleted. However, questions that run in the form

> I'm trying to do (X) in this web app in order to (get Y result) because of (Z reason). Is there an app to do that?

can be very easily edited, only slightly, to remove the request for an app and make the question about the problem to be solved. It won't invalidate any existing answers that suggest an app, and leave open the possibility that the Asker merely didn't know how to do it in the web app or the functionality was added later. They don't really need to be closed.

Comment: Related: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just edited the question to remove the emphasis on web app recommendations, then voted to undelete it.

---

As of October 31, 2023, there have been almost six years since this question was posted and the related post is still deleted, but it very recently became a case of the *Meta effect*.

Long story short, I'm no longer the same as I was when I posted this answer and voted to undelete the related question. I now wear a beard, have lost weight, and I am a moderator. Regarding the deleted question, I am not sure it is worthy to undelete it; still, I will not cancel my undelete vote.

If someone is interested in making the deleted question undelete, **please**, first take a look at [According to the statistics, Facebook users have moved from desktop to mobile](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5169/88163).

If, after that, you still want to make it to undelete instead of other options like posting a new question,

1. Submit a flag for moderation attention
2. Make a meta post

Please ensure to do not address the flag or post to any moderator by name; however, you might ask that a moderator not review your flag, i.e., because you are disputing a decision.

P.S. You might dispute the decision of one moderator but not the decision of two.

If the question gets undeleted, please bear in mind that by default, it will become a normal post. If it will require treatment, it should be locked. A comment with a link to a meta-discussion might work as a "soft lock".

Please do not post a comment to this answer to ask me to undelete the question.

Comment: If you still feel the same way, I believe you can undelete unilaterally now :)

Comment: @TheMaster Undelete votes don't age away. My undelete vote cast five years ago is still there so I can't vote to undelete again. If you would like to cast an undelete vote but do not yet have the required reputation, there is a user with the required experience who has been very active this year, and there are other two moderators. You might chat with the +10k very active user to bring this question to their attention, flag the question for moderator attention, or post an answer to bump it, i.e., saying that if you had enough rep, you would vote to undelete it.

Comment: @Rubén but did you actually try to cast undelete vote and got error? According to a staff member, you should be able to do that.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry I didn't try. My bad.

Comment: Well if you try and it works, all good, just accept animuson's answer on MSE. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry I can't accept the answer. I didn't posted the question. However, I will post a comment when I have a chance/decide to try this.

Comment: @Rubén I can accept it for you once you confirm whether it works.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I have updated my answer. TL;Dr: Don't wait for me

Comment: @Rubén thanks, noted, lmk if one day if you find out.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry Which MSE post are you referring to?

Comment: @galacticninja [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394321/how-can-a-mod-undelete-a-question-if-they-have-already-cast-an-undelete-vote-bef).