# Suggestions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

For this question,

- [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)

How is it not closed? Essentially it amounts to,

> What software can I use to download a YouTube video?

Every answer is for a different piece of software?

---

Another similar question like this,

> [Disable videos in YouTube, listen to the audio only](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15603/disable-videos-in-youtube-listen-to-the-audio-only) (every answer is for a different piece of third party software)

Answer (score 6):

Because the question is concentrating on the problem to be solved. That the only practical solution is a third-party solution is just an unfortunate side effect. If a native way is found (or added by the app developer) later, an answer to that effect can be added.

You might have a look at [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354) which goes into this in some detail.

Splitting hairs? Maybe. But we tried having recommendation questions, and they by and large ended up with answers that were just a single line and, if you were lucky, a link. By getting people to concentrate on the problem we've been getting better answers.

Comment: Hey, I'm **100% cool with it**. If you acknowledge that it's merely splitting hairs, that's awesome. As a suggestion for the site, I wouldn't close questions of this form https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/118790/1066 when questions of this form are gladly accepted https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/118819/1066 If we're just splitting hairs we should just fix them so the question is on the right side of the split.

Comment: As a user, it seemed weird that suggestions were off-topic here. most every question I've seen was answered with a suggestion to use a different tool or service.

Comment: Outwardly presume the feature there when you know it's not, get a good suggestion. State you know the feature isn't there and ask for a suggestion, be met with hasty doom. lol